# WP Get posts with any value in attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello I am trying to do this query that extract woocommerce products with 3 attributes (Collezione, Finitura, Pietre). But we can have none,1,2 or 3 filters set, so I wanna ask you which value I have to set if the filter is not set. I thought -1 but this is not working here.

Here below you can find my code. Thanks in advance.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'             => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => $cat_id,
            'operator'      => 'IN' 
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_collezione',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id', 
            'terms'         => $pa_collezione,
            'operator'      => 'IN' 
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_finitura',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'         => $pa_finitura,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),            
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_pietre',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms'         => $pa_pietre,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        )
    )
);

$products = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your terms like 'pa_collezione' are your in your **product_cat** taxonomy.

Your tax_query should just have an array of terms for the terms field.

```
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field'    => 'term_id',
           'terms'    => $array_of_term_ids,  
       ),
    )
```

Your do your filter in your terms array, not by adding extra relations.

Comment: I found the solution. I have done a check putting 'NOT IN' if category is '-1'. Now I paste solution. Thanks for help and for your time.

Comment: You can do it that way sure. But are there terms in pa_finitura or is pa_finitura a term in the product_cat? Just know when to create terms and taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution setting 'NOT IN' instead of 'IN' if parameter is not set.
Here below the solution.

```
$cat_id = $_POST['category'];
$pa_finitura= $_POST['finitura'];
$pa_collezione= $_POST['collection'];
$pa_pietre= $_POST['pietre'];

if($pa_collezione=="-1"){$cond_collezione='NOT IN';}else{$cond_collezione = 'IN';}
if($pa_finitura=="-1"){$cond_finitura='NOT IN';}else{$cond_finitura = 'IN';}
if($pa_pietre=="-1"){$cond_pietre='NOT IN';}else{$cond_pietre = 'IN';}

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'             => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => $cat_id,
            'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_collezione',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => $pa_collezione,
            'operator'      => $cond_collezione // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),

        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_finitura',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => $pa_finitura,
            'operator'      => $cond_finitura // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),


        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_pietre',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
            'terms'         => $pa_pietre,
            'operator'      => $cond_pietre // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        )
    )
);
$products = get_posts( $args );
```